# View based to Navigation Based

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a viewBasedApplication in iPhone  and I want to change it in Navigation BasedApplication using XIB file........So how can we do this so that it will work flowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to perform changes where the view is added in navigation controller in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know the difference between them if you have created a view based app and now you want to convert it navigation based.My suggestion is always make a window based app in which all things you can include which you want don't select any specific viewbase navigation or tabbar .Just change your app to window base and then add the navigation controller to your app and create the rootViewController for the navigation controller you will have navigation in your app thanks hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Implement UINavigationController from XIB library, drag drop to MainWindow xib, and put inside ur ViewController then declare

In Appdelegate.h file

```
UINavigationController *viewController;

@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *viewController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

in your MainWindow.xib, drag and drop viewController to implemented UINavigationCotroller, that solve.

For more go [Add a UINavigationController](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/)